# Shuffle List of lists containing string

Tags: python, numpy

For my bachelorthesis I need to shuffle sentences in a textcorpus.

Data looks like this:

```
[
['1', '$', '0-', '$', '10', 'Culture', ':', 'Play', 'Your', 'Way', 'to', 'China', '.'], 
['2', '02.59', 'The', 'press', 'are', 'being', 'kept', 'well', 'away', 'as', 'the', 'couple', 'meet', '21', 'local', 'dignitaries', ',', 'reports', 'the', 'BBC', "'s", 'Peter', 'Hunt', ':', 'An', 'official', 'insisted', 'all', 'journalists', 'stand', 'inside', 'a', 'pen', 'at', 'a', 'deserted', 'airport', 'runway', '.'], 
['3', '€0.25', ')', 'plus', 'PLN', '1', 'booking', 'fee', 'and', 'comfortable', 'vehicles', '.']
, 
['4', '0', "'", '6', "''", 'x', '7', "'", '6', "''", '(', '0.17m', 'x', '2.31m', ')', 'Double', 'glazed', 'window', 'to', 'the', 'side', ',', 'heated', 'towel', 'rail', ',', 'ceramic', 'floor', 'tiles', ',', 'fully', 'tiled', 'walls', ',', 'spotlights', ',', 'low', 'level', 'W/C', ',', 'shower', 'unit', 'with', 'glass', 'surround', ',', 'sink', 'with', 'mixer', 'tap', ',', 'extractor', 'fan', '.'], 
['5', '07:00', 'am', '-', 'Mon', ',', 'September', '19', '2011', 'I', 'already', 'have', 'the', 'Keystone', 'pipeline', 'running', 'through', 'my', 'properiety', 'this', 'is', 'Keystone', 'XL', 'or', 'extra', 'large', '.']
]
```

I have tried `import shuffle from random` and also `numpy.random.shuffle`, but all my minimal examples only work with lists of `ints`, not with lists of strings.

Here you can see my latter try

```
import numpy as np
raw = open('eng_news_2016_300K-sentences.txt').read()
eng3Cor = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(raw)]
eng3Cor = eng3Cor[:5]
del raw
y = np.array([np.array(xi, dtype=object) for xi in eng3Cor], dtype=object)`
```

Any advice how to do this?

EDIT:
**eng3Cor** is the **list of lists**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.shuffle()` works with lists of any data type, not just lists of ints.

This will shuffle the words in each sentence:

```
import random

for sent in eng3Cor:
    random.shuffle(sent)
```

This will just shuffle the order of the sentences:

```
import random

random.shuffle(eng3Cor)
```

Comment: But when saviong this to a variable it just returns a NoneType object. 
If I do:

`var = random.shuffle(eng3Cor)` 

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: `random.shuffle()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return a new list.

Comment: `var = eng3Cor[:]` then `random.shuffle(var)` if you don't want to modify `eng3Cor`